# Updated Variable in a While Loop

Tags: java

I have this while loop that runs as a user input fee is larger then a transaction amount. For example, if the fee is $4 and you only pay $2, it will say you still owe $2 and prompt you to enter more payments. The problem is that I cannot figure out how to update the variable transaction after a payment if it is still short. After it asks for another payment, say you are still short of the $4 and pay another $1, that will give you a total of $3 and the program should say you are still short by $1. Nonetheless, the program still says you are short by the original amount, i.e. $2.

```
while (transaction < feeSum)
{
    double underPay = feeSum - transaction;
    System.out.println("The transaction did not meet the fee by $" + underPay);
    System.out.println("Please enter another payment to complete the balance.");

    System.out.println("Enter a number of payments.");
    int paymentSize2 = keyboard.nextInt();
    double[] payments2 = new double[paymentSize2];

    System.out.println("Enter " + payments2.length + " payment(s).");
    double paymentSum2 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < payments2.length; i++)
    {
        payments2[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
        paymentSum2 = paymentSum2 + payments[i];
        transaction +=  paymentSum2; //<<<<<<< Shouldn't this update transaction? 
    }   // The second time around it should say the trans did not meet fee by $1

    if (paymentSum2 == underPay)
    {
        System.out.println("There is now no outstanding balance.");
        break;
    }
```

Comment: What is `payments[]`? And why do you never use the items in `payments2[]`? Perhaps you are confusing yourself with poor variable names.

Comment: payments2[] is a new array I added in the case that the user entered transaction is less than the sum of an arbitrarily entered sum of fees, prompting them to enter a new amount of payments that sum to be a transaction amount. The original payments[] covers the case that the transaction amount is either equal to the fee amount or greater than it.

Comment: You didn't answer the question. Why do you never use the items in `payments2[]`? You create it, put `double`s in it, and never actually use it. If you took every line with `payments2[]` out of your code, it would be exactly the same.

Comment: Ok thanks I feel ridiculous. I found out the problem. I was sitting there trying to change the code in a catch block the whole time. That's why it wasn't working. I realize it would have been way less cumbersome to use arrayLists in the first place but i'm a little rusty in my java. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remade your code a little, this will work, however it doesn't contain all that extra stuff you implemented. I don't really understand why you need those arrays.
This code doesn't handle if you pay more than you should, however that could easily be implemented in the last lines of the while loop.

```
double underPay = feeSum - transaction;
            while (underPay != 0) {
                System.out.println("The transaction did not meet the fee by $" + underPay);
                System.out.println("Please enter another payment to complete the balance.");
                int paymentSizeNext = keyboard.nextInt();
                underPay -= paymentSizeNext;


            }
            System.out.println("There is now no outstanding balance.");
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This would have been a much simpler way to do it in the first place.

Comment: Your welcome, as thanks just accept it as answer and I'll be on my way :)